# Is there any API to get the cost consumption details of an Azure Resource?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, api, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group

I need to display the costing details of a particular Azure resource in ASP .NET MVC application. I tried using the APIs given in the following links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/budgets/list, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/charges/list. I am getting error 404 as a result in one, even when the scope is right and in another I am getting code 200 ie success but it is not displaying any result. Please provide the correct APIs/way to display the code details in MVC application.

Comment: Are you using  `pay-as-you-go` or `free`  Azure subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any API to get the cost consumption details of an Azure Resource?

- Only `billing accounts`, `billing profiles`, and `pay-as-you-go` subscriptions have access to invoices.
- If you are using `Azure free subscription`, then you don't have access to the Invoice details
- If you are using Azure `pay-as-you-go` Subscription, then you need to give few permissions to access the Invoice/Azure resource costs
- Before you can use the billing API's , we need to provide permissions in Azure portal  to the API's to access the Invoice data.

Navigate to **Azure Portal** => **Cost Management + Billing**=> Your Subscription => **Invoices** =>**Access to invoice** => Select **On** => Save.
[image]

[image]

[image]

- Now we can access Invoice data/billing details using API's

Comment: Firstly, I am using a pay-as-you-go subscription. And secondly, I want to get the details at the resource level, ie how much a resource costs on a monthly or weekly basis. So, please help in this reference.

Comment: Have you set permissions to access the API, as mentioned above ?

Comment: if you want to access at resource level, then try with scope as `/subscriptions/{YoursubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{YourResourceGroupName}`

Comment: I tried that scope, but it is not displaying any results(blank), besides, that is not the problem statement, I want the cost details of a particular resource. And yes, I set permissions to access the APIs.